Card_Swiper Flutter widget gets rebuilt on swipe at every angle before threshold causing multiple requests to backend
When the user tries to swipe the card and decides to not swipe any further the widget gets rebuilt continuously causing the images to get loaded again from the backend how do I prevent this or is there any other library that can get the job done,
I have attached the code below
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_card_swiper/flutter_card_swiper.dart';
import 'package:demo/elements/candidate_details_elements/elements.dart';
import 'package:demo/api/api_calls.dart'; // Import the API calls if not already imported

class CandidatePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CandidatePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CandidatePage> createState() => _CandidatePageState();
}

class _CandidatePageState extends State<CandidatePage> {
  late ScrollController _scrollController;
  late List<Map<String, dynamic>> matchUserDetails = [];

  bool isLoading = true; // Flag to track if data is loading

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    getMatchUsers(); // Fetch data when the page is initialized
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> getMatchUsers() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true; // Set loading flag to true before fetching data
    });

    // Define your data parameters
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "uid": userValues.uid,
      "key": userValues.cookieValue,
      "gender": "Female",
      'type': 'GetUIDs'
    };

    matchUserDetails = await ApiCalls.getMatchCandidates(data);

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false; // Set loading flag to false after fetching data
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading
          ? const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(), // Show loading indicator while data is being fetched
            )
          : Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: CardSwiper(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  cardsCount: matchUserDetails.length,
                  isLoop: false,
                  backCardOffset: const Offset(0, 0),
                  allowedSwipeDirection: const AllowedSwipeDirection.only(right: true, left: true),
                  onSwipe: (previousIndex, currentIndex, direction) {
                    _scrollController.jumpTo(0.0);
                    return true;
                  },
                  cardBuilder: (context, index, x, y) {
                    if (index < matchUserDetails.length) {
                      return CandidateDetailsContainer(key: ValueKey<int>(index), scrollController: _scrollController, candidateDetails: matchUserDetails[index]);
                    } else {
                      return const SizedBox();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}


Any help would be much appreciated. ^_^
Tried:
Swiping and Widget is getting rebuilt on every angle
Expected:
Widget stays the same or at least the images don't infinitely keep accessing the backend
